# Writing a function to Trace bacterial lineage in python

Tags: python, function

I am working with Biology data where I track cells splitting. Now I want to build a lineage list for each cell. For all the cells I have the cell_number and the "mother" that gave birth to it stored in a list(see below). If the `mother_nb` = 0 it means that they were the original cell.

Now what i want to do is make a function so that it returns a complete lineage list as follows:

```
def find_lineage(cell_nb, full_ancestry):
   (code goes here)
   returns lineage
```

so that when I run this function `find_lineage(13, full_ancestry)`

I get a list
`[11, 1, 0]`

````
experiment[0].family_tree
[{'cell_nb': 1, 'mother_nb': 0},
 {'cell_nb': 2, 'mother_nb': 0},
 {'cell_nb': 3, 'mother_nb': 0},
 {'cell_nb': 4, 'mother_nb': 0},
 {'cell_nb': 5, 'mother_nb': 0},
 {'cell_nb': 6, 'mother_nb': 2},
 {'cell_nb': 7, 'mother_nb': 3},
 {'cell_nb': 8, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 9, 'mother_nb': 6},
 {'cell_nb': 10, 'mother_nb': 2},
 {'cell_nb': 11, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 12, 'mother_nb': 8},
 {'cell_nb': 13, 'mother_nb': 11},
 {'cell_nb': 14, 'mother_nb': 8},
 {'cell_nb': 15, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 16, 'mother_nb': 12},
 {'cell_nb': 17, 'mother_nb': 13},
 {'cell_nb': 18, 'mother_nb': 15},
 {'cell_nb': 19, 'mother_nb': 11},
 {'cell_nb': 20, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 21, 'mother_nb': 11},
 {'cell_nb': 22, 'mother_nb': 18},
 {'cell_nb': 23, 'mother_nb': 20},
 {'cell_nb': 24, 'mother_nb': 15},
 {'cell_nb': 25, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 26, 'mother_nb': 25},
 {'cell_nb': 27, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 28, 'mother_nb': 20},
 {'cell_nb': 29, 'mother_nb': 26},
 {'cell_nb': 30, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 31, 'mother_nb': 27},
 {'cell_nb': 32, 'mother_nb': 25},
 {'cell_nb': 33, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 34, 'mother_nb': 30},
 {'cell_nb': 35, 'mother_nb': 27},
 {'cell_nb': 36, 'mother_nb': 33},
 {'cell_nb': 37, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 38, 'mother_nb': 30},
 {'cell_nb': 39, 'mother_nb': 33},
 {'cell_nb': 40, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 41, 'mother_nb': 37},
 {'cell_nb': 42, 'mother_nb': 37},
 {'cell_nb': 43, 'mother_nb': 40},
 {'cell_nb': 44, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 45, 'mother_nb': 40},
 {'cell_nb': 46, 'mother_nb': 44},
 {'cell_nb': 47, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 48, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 49, 'mother_nb': 44},
 {'cell_nb': 50, 'mother_nb': 47},
 {'cell_nb': 51, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 52, 'mother_nb': 47},
 {'cell_nb': 53, 'mother_nb': 48},
 {'cell_nb': 54, 'mother_nb': 47},
 {'cell_nb': 55, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 56, 'mother_nb': 48},
 {'cell_nb': 57, 'mother_nb': 51},
 {'cell_nb': 58, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 59, 'mother_nb': 55},
 {'cell_nb': 60, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 61, 'mother_nb': 58},
 {'cell_nb': 62, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 63, 'mother_nb': 60},
 {'cell_nb': 64, 'mother_nb': 63},
 {'cell_nb': 65, 'mother_nb': 60},
 {'cell_nb': 66, 'mother_nb': 62},
 {'cell_nb': 67, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 68, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 69, 'mother_nb': 67},
 {'cell_nb': 70, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 71, 'mother_nb': 68},
 {'cell_nb': 72, 'mother_nb': 70},
 {'cell_nb': 73, 'mother_nb': 68},
 {'cell_nb': 74, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 75, 'mother_nb': 74},
 {'cell_nb': 76, 'mother_nb': 70},
 {'cell_nb': 77, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 78, 'mother_nb': 74},
 {'cell_nb': 79, 'mother_nb': 0},
 {'cell_nb': 80, 'mother_nb': 77},
 {'cell_nb': 81, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 82, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 83, 'mother_nb': 82},
 {'cell_nb': 84, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 85, 'mother_nb': 1},
 {'cell_nb': 86, 'mother_nb': 1}]```
````

Comment: SO is not a free coding site. Please make some sort of attempt

Comment: Hi thank you for your feedback. I tried solving this problem for several hours and was unable to resolve it. I did write a recursive function that worked under very limited conditions. I decided against posting my own code here because I thought it would detract from the question.

Comment: Quite the opposite. Putting down a failed attempt is better than none at all

Comment: Ok great next time I will. Thank you for helping me improve my SO questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `full_ancestry` is a list sorted in increasing order of `cell_nb` and no numbers are skipped, the approach below would work.

```py
def find_lineage(cell_nb, full_ancestry):
    ancestry = []
    while cell_nb:
        cell_nb = full_ancestry[cell_nb - 1]['mother_nb']
        ancestry.append(cell_nb)
    return ancestry

print(find_lineage(13, full_ancestry))
```

Output:

```
[11, 1, 0]
```

If the list items can be in any order, consider creating a map and using it.

```py
ancestry_map = {}
for ancestry in full_ancestry:
    ancestry_map[ancestry['cell_nb']] = ancestry['mother_nb']

def find_lineage(cell_nb, ancestry_map):
    ancestry = []
    while cell_nb:
        cell_nb = ancestry_map[cell_nb]
        ancestry.append(cell_nb)
    return ancestry

print(find_lineage(13, ancestry_map))
```

Output:

```
[11, 1, 0]
```